# Error in using same foriegn key in multiple tables django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table named

```
   class student(models.Model):
       std_name= models.CharField(max_length=20 , blank=False, null=False)
       std_username = models.CharField(max_length=20 , blank=False, null=False)
```

And another table named std_admission.

```
   class std_admission(models.Model):
        admission_date= models.CharField(max_length=20 , blank=False, null=False)
        std_name = models.ForeignKey(student, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
        std_username = models.ForeignKey(student, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

When i type makemigrations i get this error
clashes with reverse accessor

Comment: So if i manually add related_name='+' in the models im using the foriegnkey it should work right? And will be able to get the data stored in the field called (foreignkey) in the model in which i have used it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually add a "related_name" for reverse search.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

The default is `foreignmodel_set`, but if you use it twice, you will have a conflict, that's why it is needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should write class names always with capital letters such as:

```py
class Student(models.Model)
```

Second, you don't need to add twice the foreign key from `Student` table.

`std_name = models.ForeignKey`

is enough.

When you add both they don't take a reference of the student name and the username. Instead, they both give the pk of the `student` instance.
You'd better change the name of the foreignkey from `std_name` to only `student`.

`student= models.ForeignKey`

Now, if you want to obtain the username of the student from your admission table you can do it like this:

`std_admission.objects.get(pk=some pk).std_name.username`

this will give you the student username for this particular instance of `std_admission`. If you use filter instead of `get` then you will not be able to use

`.std_name.username`

as filter will return a queryset and you'll have to access values using

`[i].std_name.username.`